# Como funciona a implementação de tabelas hash?

Tags: característica-linguagem, hashmap

O conceito de *hashes* (ou tabelas *hash*) já vem embutido em várias linguagens de programação como Javascript, Python, Ruby, etc, e é conhecida por ser muito mais rápida que, por exemplo, listas encadeadas. Ela associa pares chave-valor assim:

```ruby
meuHash = []
meuHash["minha chave"] = "meu valor"
```

Minha dúvida é: Como elas são implementadas? Ou seja, o que acontece por trás quando incluímos ou buscamos um valor em um *hash*?

Apenas sei que sua implementação é diferente de estruturas encadeadas como pilhas, filas, listas, árvores binárias, etc.

Comment: Lembrando que isso é um dicionário. 'Hash' é uma metonímia. A implementação pode usar hash, mas também pode usar vetor, ou árvore, ou outra coisa. A implementação do dicionário Python muda de hash para árvore na versão 3.7 pois os valores das chaves passam a ser mantidos ordenados.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

## Cada coisa é uma coisa

Antes de mais nada, é importante entender que cada tipo de estrutura de dados possui uma aplicação mais específica. Então, dizer que *hashes* são mais rápidos que listas encadeadas é comparar laranjas com bananas.

Uma "tabela" é bastante eficiente para recuperar um elemento contido nela a partir de uma **chave**. Isso significa que é rápido encontrar uma agulha no palheiro se você tiver uma forma (*hash*) de identificar a agulha.

Entretanto, percorrer uma tabela inteiro é, em geral, menos eficiente que percorrer uma lista inteiro.

Além disso, somente uma lista baseada em vetores permite acessar elementos aleatórios de forma eficiente.

## *Hashes*

São valores numéricos calculados por uma função a partir de um valor original de tamanho arbitrário. Existem vários algoritmos de *hash*, sendo que os melhores são os que emitem o menor número possível de *hashes* repetidos.

Por exemplo, a classe `String` do Java possui o seguinte método para gerar o *hash code*:

```java
public int More ...hashCode() {
    int h = hash;
    if (h == 0) {
        int off = offset;
        char val[] = value;
        int len = count;

        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            h = 31*h + val[off++];
        }
        hash = h;
    }
    return h;
}
```

A documentação do método afirma que o *hash* é calculado da seguinte forma:

```java
s[0]*31^(n-1) + s[1]*31^(n-2) + ... + s[n-1]
```

Onde:

- `s[i]`: `i`-ésimo caractere da String.
- `m`: tamanho da String, em caracteres

Em resumo, gerar um *hash* é como gerar um ID numérico para o objeto.

Em Java, qualquer objeto pode ter uma implementação próprio do `hashCode`. Essa implementação deve considerar todos os atributos que identificam o objeto. É importante que objetos diferentes tenham *hashes* diferentes, tanto quanto possível.

## Tabelas de *Hashes*

O número gerado por uma função `hash` pode ser usado para localizar facilmente um objeto numa espécie de "tabela".

Internamente, no Java por exemplo, essa tabela é um vetor. A cada posição do vetor é atribuído uma faixa de números. Seria como *slots* de uma prateleira.

### Armazenando valores

Vamos supor que criamos um `Hashtable` e o vetor interno tem 10 posições (*slots*). Suponha ainda que adicionamos objetos e informemos chaves valores de *hash* variem de 1 a 100. Dessa forma, *hashes* que retornem valores de 1 a 10 serão colocados no primeiro *slot*, os que retornem valores de 11 a 20 no segundo *slot* e assim por diante.

Se adicionarmos um objeto (1) cujo *hash* da chave seja 20 ele será colocado no segundo *slot*. Se adicionarmos outro objeto (2) com chave de *hash* 45 ele será colocado quinto *slot*. Se adicionarmos ainda outro objeto (3) com chave de *hash* 15, ele será colocando também no segundo *slot*. Teríamos a seguinte estrutura de dados:

```java
Slot 1: 
Slot 2: Objeto 1, Objeto 3
Slot 3: 
Slot 4: 
Slot 5: Objeto 2 
Slot 6: 
Slot 7: 
Slot 8: 
Slot 9: 
Slot 10:
```

Note que cada item da tabela é também um tipo de vetor. Em Java, na classe `Hashtable`, isso é implementado através de uma lista ligada de objetos do tipo `Entry` (entrada).

### Recuperando valores

Então, para recuperar um objeto, basta passar a chave para a tabela, esta calculará o *hash* e irá diretamente ao *slot* para recuperar o item.

Continuando o exemplo mais acima, se eu quisesse recuperar o Objeto 3, teria que passar a chave do mesmo. A tabela iria calcular o *hash code* da chave, que retornaria o valor 15. *Hashes* sempre retornam o mesmo valor para a mesma chave. Então com uma conta simples eu sei que o item será encontrado no segundo *slot*. Porém, como ainda temos uma lista de objetos, a tabela terá que percorrer a lista de entradas do *slot* 2 e verificar, um a um, qual é realmente o Objeto 3.

## Implicações

As explicações acima possuem várias implicações:

- Se houver muita colisão de *hashes*, muitos objetos acabarão caindo em poucos *slots*. havendo uma distribuição ruim, cada vez que for necessário recuperar um item a eficiência será ruim, pois será necessário percorrer a lista de elementos do *slot* e comparar um a um.
- O tamanho interno da tabela precisa ser bem calculado, para que não haja muitos itens em cada *slot*, nem muitos *slots* vazios. Na implementação do Java, quando os *slots* começam a ficar cheios o `Hashtable` aumenta o número de slots e faz uma redistribuição.
- No Java, o método que gera o *hash* pode ser chamado várias vezes, então é importante cuidar do desempenho e fazer *cache* do valor quando possível.
- Dependendo da implementação da *hash table*, incluir muitos itens repetidamente pode ser bem ineficiente, já que haverá repetidas pausas para adicionar novos *slots* e redistribuir os elementos.

## Diferentes tipos de implementações

Uma grande parte do que foi descrito acima é apenas um dos tipos possíveis de implementação de uso de *hashes* para recuperar valores.

Por exemplo, em Java, existe o *TreeMap*, uma "tabela" cujos *hashes* das entradas não ficam armazenadas num vetor, mas em uma árvore binária.

Há várias implicações nisso. Dependendo do balanceamento da árvore pode ser mais ou menos eficiente recuperar elementos. Comparando uma árvore balanceada com uma implementação de vetores com *slots* cheios a árvore iria ganhar.

Porém, já fiz algumas implementações que precisavam carregar árvores bem grandes em memória e o `TreeMap` foi muito mais eficiente.

Comment: Excelente resposta! Abordou todos os detalhes de forma simples.

Comment: Muito esclarecedor a explicação.

Answer (score 0):

Uma tabela **hash** é uma estrutura que permite associar uma chave a um valor e, posteriormente, ter acesso ao valor a partir de sua chave associada. A chave é transformada por uma função em uma posição na tabela; usando sempre essa transformação, a localização de chaves na tabela é realizada rapidamente.

Em Java, essa estrutura de dados é implementada por objetos da classe Hashtable. Para manipular elementos na tabela hash, são usados os métodos put(), que armazena um par de objetos especificados na tabela, get(), que retorna o objeto valor associado ao objeto chave especificado, e remove(), que remove o par de objetos com a chave especificada. É também possível consultar se uma determinada chave existe na tabela, com o método containsKey(), ou se um determinado valor está presente na tabela associado a qualquer chave, com o método contains(). O número de pares de elementos na tabela pode ser obtido com o método size().

Comment: Eu na verdade não queria saber como usar, mas como isso é implementado por trás, ou seja, o que acontece quando buscamos ou incluímos um valor num *hash*.