# Como retornar a posição de um elemento no HashSet?

Tags: java, lista

Tenho a seguinte estrutura:
`HashSet<Contato> contatos = new HashSet<Contato>();`
Como retornar a posição de um determinado elemento Contato que está contido no HashSet?

Eu estava pesquisando e encontrei uma maneira de consegui retornar a posição, mas não sei se o código abaixo está **totalmente** certo:

```
public int getPosicao(Contato c) {
    int posicao = 0;
    for (Iterator<Contato> it = contatos.iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
        Contato contato = it.next();
        if (contato.equals(c)) {
            break;
        }
        posicao++;
    }
    return posicao;
}
```

Comment: Hashsets não são ordenados (mas é importante perguntar isso e ter uma resposta, então aqui vai um +1).

Comment: @Renan postei um código na minha pergunta..

Comment: @PedroRangel Sim, seu código está certo. Eu *acho* (faz um tempo que não mexo com Java, não me lembro bem) que você pode simplificar isso usando `for ( Contato contato : contatos ) { ... }` (foreach). Lembrando sempre que a posição retornada pode mudar no decorrer do programa, é claro.

Comment: @mgibsonbr blz entao^^

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Como [apontado por Renan nos comentários](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/35345/como-retornar-a-posi%C3%A7%C3%A3o-de-um-elemento-no-hashset#comment68528_35345), `HashSet`s não são ordenados, de modo que não faz muito sentido se falar na "posição" de um elemento dentro do mesmo. Mudanças no conjunto - ou mesmo a criação de um outro objeto `HashSet` com os mesmos elementos - podem alterar completamente sua ordem.

Entretanto, se você quiser uma ordem definida, você pode optar pelo [`LinkedHashSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html) ou pelo [`TreeSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html) - o primeiro mantém os elementos na ordem em que foram inseridos, e o segundo usa um comparador (ou a ordem natural dos objetos) para estabelecer a ordem dos elementos do conjunto. A partir daí você pode por exemplo iterar sobre os elementos para descobrir o seu índice (ineficiente, concordo, mas que eu saiba é o único meio).

Para mais informações sobre como funciona o `HashSet` - e por que eles não são ordenados, e por que a ordem pode mudar à medida que a coleção muda - ver a pergunta relacionada: ["Como funciona a implementação de tabelas hash?"](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/27827/215)

Answer (score 4):

Um hashset é como um livro, no qual as chaves são o sumário e os valores são os capítulos.

Em outras palavras... Quando você insere um elemento em um hashset, é gerado um [hash](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fun%C3%A7%C3%A3o_hash) do objeto. Daí você tem uma estrutura que guarda informações em pares. Cada par tem de um lado o hash do objeto e do outro uma referência pro objeto.

Acontece que hashes são geralmente strings bem... aleatórias. Por exemplo, supondo que o algoritmo de hash seja o [MD5](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5):

- o hash da string `foo` é `acbd18db4cc2f85cedef654fccc4a4d8`;
- Já o hash de `bar` é `37b51d194a7513e45b56f6524f2d51f2`;
- E de `baz` é `73feffa4b7f6bb68e44cf984c85f6e88`.

Se você fosse ordenar os hashes por ordem alfabética ou hexadecimal, teria que reindexar o conjunto a cada elemento adicionado. Isso deixaria as inserções lentas, e um dos objetivos do hashset é ser rápido.

Pra complicar, é possível haver colisão de hashes. Isso ocorre quando dois objetos tem o mesmo hash. Nesse caso, é comum que um hashset adicione um pouco de sal (isso é um termo técnico!) a um dos objetos e gere um novo hash diferente pra ele. Assim a bagunça nos índices fica maior ainda.

Talvez você queira usar um mapa de hashes encadeados. Essa estrutura garante a ordem de inserção e existe uma classe em Java para isso: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html