# Comparar o elemento com o resto da lista Python

Tags: python, comparação

Preciso criar um programa onde na lista dada, se o nome estiver repetido ele coloca uma numeração. Por exemplo: nomes = [maria, joao, maria] o resultado deve ser resultado = [maria, joao, maria1]

Outro exemplo: nomes = [eduardo, joao, eduardo, eduardo] resultado = [eduardo, joao, eduardo1, eduardo2]

montei um codigo onde compara com o próximo nome, não sei como faz para continuar a comparação.

segue o meu codigo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Seja bem vinda Tatiane, pode ser mais especifica? [Edite](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/404021/edit) a pergunta e dê algum exemplo prático ou  coloque parte do seu código.

Answer (score 1):

A solução desse problema é simples e pode ser facilmente acalcando com o uso de uma [Tabela de Hash](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/27915/137387) para contabilizar as repetições de cada nome enquanto itera pela lista de nomes.

Em python uma tabela de hash é compreendida como um [dicionário](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict).

O algoritmo é simples:

- `nomes` é a lista de entradas para o algoritmo.
- Aloca em `contadores` a referência para uma tabela de hash vazia para então manter um contador de repetições de nomes.
- Aloca e `resultado` uma lista vazia que receberá um nome da lista nomes apensado ou não da sua contagem.
- Itere a cada nome `n` contido na lista `nomes`:

  - Verifique se a chave `n` existe no dicionário `contadores`:

    - Caso a chave `n` exista em `contadores`, adicione `n` apensado do valor de `contadores[n]` ao `resultado` e incrementa em `1` o valor de `contadores[n]`.
    - Caso a chave `n` não exista em `contadores`, adiciona `n` ao `resultado` e inicializa o `contador[n]` em `1`.
- imprima o `resultado`

```python
nomes = ['eduardo', 'joao', 'eduardo', 'eduardo', 'maria', 'joao', 'maria'] 

contadores = {}       #Cria uma tabela de hash para manter um contador de repetições de nomes.
resultado = []        #Lista que receberá um nome da lista nomes apensado da sua contagem.

#Para cada nome n em nomes...
for n in nomes:
  #...se n for chave em contadores...
  if n in contadores:    
    resultado.append(f'{n}{contadores[n]}')  #...adiciona n apensado a sua contagem ao resultado.
    contadores[n] += 1                       #...incrementa o contador para n.
  #...caso n não seja chave em contadores...
  else:                         
    resultado.append(n)                      #...adiciona n ao resultado.
    contadores[n] = 1                        #...inicializa o contador n e uma ocorrencia.  

print(resultado)
#['eduardo', 'joao', 'eduardo1', 'eduardo2', 'maria', 'joao1', 'maria1']
```

<sup>Teste o exemplo no [Ideone.com](https://ideone.com/hsK2lZ)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar um [dicionário](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) para salvar quantas vezes um nome já apareceu.

```
names = ['eduardo', 'joao', 'eduardo', 'eduardo', 'joao']

d = {}

for i in range(len(names)):
    if names[i] in d:
        d[names[i]] += 1
        names[i] += str(d[names[i]])
    else:
        d[names[i]] = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Com dictionary é possível guardar os nomes e o número de vezes que vai repetindo:

```
    def usernamesSystem(u):
        cont = 0
        aDict = {}
        result = []
        for i in range(len(u)):
            cont = checkKey(aDict, u[i]) # verifica o numero de ocorrencia do nome
            if cont == 0:
                aDict[u[i]] = 1 # primeira ocorrencia, guarda valor 1 no dictionary
                result.append(u[i]) # carrega o array de output com a palavra 
            else:
                aDict.update({u[i]: cont + 1 }) # atualiza as ocorrencias do nome no dictionary
                result.append(u[i] + str(cont)) # carrega o array de output com o nome concatenado com o numero de vezes repetido
        return result # array de output com o resultado

    def checkKey(dict, key): 
        if key in dict.keys(): 
            return dict[key] # retorna o numero de ocorrencias quando ja existe no dictionary
        else: 
            return 0 # retorna 0 se não existir
```

Answer (score 0):

coloco agora a resposta mais completa, com a classe que utilizei.

```
class Usernames:

    @staticmethod
    def usernamesSystem(u):
        cont = 0
        aDict = {}
        result = []
        for i in range(len(u)):
            cont = Usernames.checkKey(aDict, u[i])
            if cont == 0:
                aDict[u[i]] = 1
                result.append(u[i])
            else:
                aDict.update({u[i]: cont + 1 })
                result.append(u[i] + str(cont))
        return result

    @staticmethod
    def checkKey(dict, key): 
        if key in dict.keys(): 
            return dict[key] 
        else: 
            return 0

nomes = ['eduardo', 'joao', 'eduardo', 'eduardo']
print(Usernames.usernamesSystem(nomes))
```

Comment: Muito obrigada! deu certo!!!!

Comment: Boa. Não te esqueças de dar feedback (votar).