# Como percorrer um array de objetos, somar propriedades específicas e unificar esses objetos onde tiver uma propriedade específica igual a outra?

Tags: javascript

Tenho um array de objetos que tem essa estrutura abaixo:

```
listaProdutos = 
[
      {nome:'Teclado',preco:28.00},
      {nome:'Mouse',preco:36.00},
      {nome:'Monitor',preco:500.00},
      {nome:'CPU',preco:800.00},
      {nome:'Teclado',preco:28.00},
      {nome:'Monitor',preco:500.00},
];
```

Minha intenção seria que fosse gerado um array de objetos com o resultado abaixo:

```
novoLista = 
[
    {nome:'Teclado',preco:56.00},
    {nome:'Mouse',preco:36.00},
    {nome:'Monitor',preco:1000.00},
    {nome:'CPU',preco:800.00} 
];
```

Você poderiam me ajudar com a melhor abordagem para essa situação ?

Comment: Veja qual seria a estrutura de tabela hash / tabela de espalhamento / _hash table_ no JS (conjunto de pares de chave/valor em que a chave não se repete)? Percorre o array e vai vendo se os nomes já existem como chaves da hash table, se já existirem você atualiza o valor da mesma (soma o que já estava com o do objeto), senão acrescenta o novo par.

Comment: Tabela hash é uma estrutura de dados essencial e ubíqua em computação, presente nas linguagens sob diversos nomes (dicionários, maps, hashmaps, etc), se não conhece recomendo que estude e entenda bem seu princípio de funcionamento, pois se aplica a uma diversidade de situações. Aqui no SOpt mesmo tem uma boa explicação: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/27827/357

Comment: Estou mantendo um _benchmark_ com cada resposta desta pergunta. Para não ser injusto com nenhuma resposta, sugiro que o iminente utilizador de qualquer um dos códigos abaixo altere os valores padrão do número de elementos do _benchmark_ para espelhar as necessidades do projeto. A performance de cada solução varia significativamente de acordo com o número de itens únicos (`NAMES_COUNT`) e de elementos totais (`ITEMS_COUNT`). **[Aqui está o link.](https://jsbench.me/6xkkroain8/1)**

Comment: @LuizFelipe fiz simulações com 3 cenários de testes, com 1000 itens, 100 e 10 e os resultados são completamente diferentes, seria interessante montar esses 3 cenários para termos um bom report ao final

Comment: @RicardoPontual, pois é, e também varia com ordens de grandeza maiores que `1e3`. Tente com `1e5` ou `1e6`, por exemplo. :P Por isso que sugeri que o utilizador testasse varias conforme a quantidade aproximada que trabalhará. Mas convenhamos que JS realmente não é linguagem para esse tipo de operação com _muitos_ itens, então essa minha ideia de _benchmark_ é meio _pointless_ em primeiro lugar...

Comment: Galera, muito obrigado por serem solícitos. Eu ainda sou leigo na questão de testar desempenho no benchmark . Essa pergunta é com base em um curso que estou fazer e fiquei com dúvidas. Como não queria fazer coisas esdrúxulas (que era como eu sabia fazer) eu preferi consultar aqui, para me agregar conhecimento. Mas sinceramente, na opinião de vocês. Quais das respostas teria um desempenho melhor com "poucos dados" e com "muitos dados" ? A diferença seria perceptível com "muitos dados" ? Pelo que vi lá, com visão de leigo, a do Ricardo Pontual foi a que me pareceu ter o melhor resultado.

Comment: @GatodeSchrödinger, com poucos dados a diferença é mínima e quase imperceptível, uma vez que (embora percentualmente a diferença seja visível) será tudo muito rápido. Em quantidades maiores, aí sim fará diferença. No seu caso, se a quantidade de dados for pequena, escolha o código que mais lhe agrada. Sem dúvidas todas as soluções postadas aqui são muito elegantes. :-)

Comment: @GatodeSchrödinger depende de a partir de qual numero voce considera "muitos dados" ou "poucos dados". O legal dessas respostas é que são soluções distinas, com resultados de benchmark diferentes de acordo com a situacao. No bench. que o Luiz Felipe mostrou, a solucao dele é excelente para casos de muitos objetos no array (+1000), mas para caso mais simples, a solucao do Ricardo Pontual é a que melhor se adapta. Acho inclusive que deveriamos estudar um pouco mais sobre o `Map`. Pra mim essa foi a pergunta com as respostas mais interessantes do ano :D .

Comment: Sim, @CmteCardeal, Mas a ideia é realmente essa. Pra mim pode ser "poucos dados", mas futuramente posso precisar da solução para "muitos dados". Ou outros usuários que entrem atrás de uma solução, possa variarem entre querer a resposta pra "muitos dados" e "poucos dados". A ideia é que a resposta realmente me atenda. Mas o espírito geral é que possa ajudar futuros usuários também, com necessidades iguais a minha, porém com quantidades de dados que possam variar de um pra outro.

Comment: eu confesso que gostei muito de todas as abordagens, e o teste deixa claro os pontos fortes e fracos de cada implementação em cenários diversos, isso faz muita diferença e deixa a pergunta muito mais rica com além de respostas, análises comparando cada uma delas :)

Comment: Por favor evitem longas discussões nos comentários; a conversa de vocês foi [movida para o chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/119370/discussion-on-question-by-gato-de-schrodinger-como-percorrer-um-array-de-objetos)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pode-se usar o método [`reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) para iterar em cada elemento do array, remover os duplicados e somar. Por exemplo:

```js
listaProdutos = 
[
      {nome:'Teclado',preco:28.00},
      {nome:'Mouse',preco:36.00},
      {nome:'Monitor',preco:500.00},
      {nome:'CPU',preco:800.00},
      {nome:'Teclado',preco:28.00},
      {nome:'Monitor',preco:500.00},
];

const novoLista = listaProdutos.reduce((soma, cur) => {
  // guarda o nome atual e verifica se existe repetido
  let nome = cur.nome;
  let repetido = soma.find(elem => elem.nome === nome)
  // se for repetido soma, caso contrário adiciona o elemento ao novo array
  if (repetido) repetido.preco += cur.preco;
  else soma.push(cur);
  // retorna o elemento agrupado e somado
  return soma;
}, []);

console.log(novoLista);
```

Comment: Legal! :) +1 Só acho válido observar que como `reduce` e  `find` têm complexidade O(n), este código tem complexidade quadrática, o que pode ser ruim em casos de grande quantidade de itens.

Comment: Galera, vou verificar amanhã de tarde. Hoje estou super exausto. Muito obrigado.

Comment: @LuizFelipe, por curiosidade criei um benchmark entre as duas soluções e o resultado é quase igual, sendo o reduce ligeiramente mais performático: https://jsben.ch/oQc4s

Comment: A diferença é perceptível com uma amostra de dados um pouco maior, [veja](https://jsbench.me/6xkkroain8/1). Quanto maior o número de elementos, maior é a diferença. Em amostras pequenas, a diferença de velocidade é ínfima e faz pouca diferença.

Comment: Esse reduce com o find dentro foi bem interessante.

Comment: Todas as respostas foram ótimas, me serviram e foram devidamente "upvotadas" por mim.  Porém essa aqui foi a que achei mais simples e a que eu pude entender melhor. Apesar de eu não saber se foi a mais performática. Obrigado a todos!

Comment: obrigado @GatodeSchrödinger, os testes, que aliás o Luiz Felipe fez um ótimo trabalho de juntar e manter mostram que esse algoritmo que usei é o mais rápido com poucos elementos, eu fiz um teste com até 30 ele é o mais rápido, dai até 100 já fica na média, e com mais de 100 começa a cair a performace, sendo o mais lento com 1000 elementos para cima, deixo comentado aqui para quem ver essa ótima pergunta e quiser experimentar algum dos algoritmos :)

Comment: Nada. Eu que agradeço :)

Comment: Isso tá sendo muito útil pra mim. Se pudesse, dava +2. hahaha'

Answer (score 5):

Você pode acumular cada `nome` único e ir somando o `preco` de cada objeto por `nome` correspondente. Uma vez que o mapa tenha sido completo, gera-se o novo array. Uma forma de manter os objetos a partir de uma chave única é utilizar a estrutura de dados [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) do JavaScript.

Algo assim:

```js
function sumByPropName(nameProp, sumProp, arr) {
  const map = new Map();

  for (const obj of arr) {
    // Chave que utilizaremos para o mapa. A `key` corresponde a cada "nome" único.
    const key = obj[nameProp];

    // Caso nenhum objeto já tiver sido registrado para a chave atual, devemos o
    // inserir pela primeira vez.
    if (!map.has(key)) {
      map.set(key, obj);

      // Podemos pular para a próxima iteração, já que o valor correspondente
      // já está incluído no `obj`.
      continue;
    }

    // Caos já tenha sido registrado, é só somar ao valor já armazenado.
    map.get(key)[sumProp] += obj[sumProp];
  }

  // Converter o mapa em array:
  return [...map.values()];
}

const original = [
  { nome: 'Teclado', preco: 28.0 },
  { nome: 'Mouse', preco: 36.0 },
  { nome: 'Monitor', preco: 500.0 },
  { nome: 'CPU', preco: 800.0 },
  { nome: 'Teclado', preco: 28.0 },
  { nome: 'Monitor', preco: 500.0 }
];

// Queremos identificar elementos únicos pela propriedade `nome` (1º arg.)
// O somatório corresponde à propriedade `preco` (2º arg.)
console.log(sumByPropName('nome', 'preco', original));
```

A complexidade da função acima seria algo como `O(n + m)`, sendo `n` o número de elementos do array original e `m` o número de `nome`s únicos.

- O `n` vem do `for` (que é indispensável neste tipo de situação).
- O `m` (que muitas vezes é ínfimo e pode ser desconsiderado) vem da necessidade de se converter o mapa para array ao final da função.

Se `Map` não puder ser utilizado (foi introduzido no ECMAScript 2015), pode-se utilizar `Object.create(null)` como substituto.

Tentei já explicar direto pelo código, qualquer dúvida deixe nos comentários que tento editar para esclarecer.

Comment: Galera, vou verificar amanhã de tarde. Hoje estou super exausto. Muito obrigado.

Answer (score 5):

Vou compartilhar a minha solução, sendo esta, ao meu ver, uma alternativa decente as outras respostas.

Código:

```js
const listaProdutos = [
  { nome: 'Teclado', preco: 28.0 },
  { nome: 'Mouse', preco: 36.0 },
  { nome: 'Monitor', preco: 500.0 },
  { nome: 'CPU', preco: 800.0 },
  { nome: 'Teclado', preco: 28.0 },
  { nome: 'Monitor', preco: 500.0 },
];

const resObject = {};

listaProdutos.forEach((elem) => {
  const valorAnterior = resObject[elem.nome] || 0;

  resObject[elem.nome] = valorAnterior + elem.preco;
});

const novoLista = Object.keys(resObject).map((key) => {
  return { nome: key, preco: resObject[key] };
});

console.log(novoLista);
```

As explicações:

- `const resObject = {};` é um objeto temporário para salvar o valor de `nome` como uma key deste objeto, além de manter um valor acumulado de cada `preco` da lista de produtos.
- `forEach` pra iterar sobre os elementos de lista.
- `valorAnterior` recebe o valor já salvo no `resObject` de acordo com a chave (`Teclado`, `Mouse`, etc...). Se a chave não existir, adotamos o valor `0`.
- `resObject[elem.nome] = valorAnterior + elem.preco;` basicamente, adicionar uma chave ao objeto `resObject` com um valor inicial de acordo com `elem.preco`. Se a chave já existe, ela já tem um valor, então faremos uma soma.

Neste ponto, se você der um `console.log`, verá o objeto `resObject` com as chaves com o nome dos nomes de produtos da lista e os respectivos valores já somados.

```js
const listaProdutos = [
  { nome: 'Teclado', preco: 28.0 },
  { nome: 'Mouse', preco: 36.0 },
  { nome: 'Monitor lcd', preco: 500.0 },
  { nome: 'CPU', preco: 800.0 },
  { nome: 'Teclado', preco: 28.0 },
  { nome: 'Monitor', preco: 500.0 },
];

const resObject = {};

listaProdutos.forEach((elem) => {
  const valorAnterior = resObject[elem.nome] || 0;

  resObject[elem.nome] = valorAnterior + elem.preco;
});

console.log(resObject)
```

A partir de agora, o que faremos é associar a chave do `resObject` para um objeto com a propriedade `nome`:

```
 return { nome: key, ...}
```

e o `preco` será o valor desta chave usando `resObject[key]`:

```
return { nome: key, preco: resObject[key] };
```

---

Adicionei um `toFixed` apenas pra ficar como deseja para `novoLista`:

```js
const listaProdutos = [
  { nome: 'Teclado', preco: 28.0 },
  { nome: 'Mouse', preco: 36.0 },
  { nome: 'Monitor lcd', preco: 500.0 },
  { nome: 'CPU', preco: 800.0 },
  { nome: 'Teclado', preco: 28.0 },
  { nome: 'Monitor', preco: 500.0 },
];

const resObject = {};

listaProdutos.forEach((elem) => {
  const valorAnterior = resObject[elem.nome] || 0;

  resObject[elem.nome] = valorAnterior + elem.preco;
});

const novoLista = Object.keys(resObject).map((key) => {
  return { nome: key, preco: parseFloat(resObject[key]).toFixed(2) };
});


console.log(novoLista);
```

Comment: Legal! Coloquei no [benchmark](https://jsbench.me/6xkkroain8/1) para não ficar de fora. :-)

Comment: boa, acho que vai ficar muito boa essa pergunta, com várias soluções e benchmark :)

Comment: Obrigado, verificarei todas.

Answer (score 5):

Ainda no tema [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) é possível utilizar outra abordagem.

Faça duma instancia de `Map` um índice para os elementos do [Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) `novoLista`
que será populado inicialmente com uma cópia do primeiro objeto da lista `listaProdutos` cujo a propriedade `nome` ainda não tenha sido indexada.
Caso já haja um índice que seja a propriedade `nome` apenas some `preço` ao `preço` do elemento já indexado.

```js
let listaProdutos = 
[
      {nome:'Teclado',preco:28.00},
      {nome:'Mouse',preco:36.00},
      {nome:'Monitor',preco:500.00},
      {nome:'CPU',preco:800.00},
      {nome:'Teclado',preco:28.00},
      {nome:'Monitor',preco:500.00},
];

let novoLista = [];

let m = new Map();

//Para todos os elementos de listaProdutos...
for(let prod of listaProdutos){
  //Verifica se índice contiver a chave prod.nome...
  if (m.has(prod.nome)){
    //No item indexado por prod.nome no array novoLista incrementa o preço registrado com o novo preço.
    novoLista[m.get(prod.nome)].preco += prod.preco;                          
  } else {
    //Cria um índice nomeado pelo valor de prod.nome apontando para o mais novo elemento do array novoLista
    m.set(prod.nome, novoLista.push({nome:prod.nome,preco:prod.preco}) - 1);  
  }
}

console.log(novoLista);
```

Créditos ao [Luiz Felipe](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/69296/luiz-felipe) quem colocou o código acima na forma de uma função:

```js
let listaProdutos = 
[
  {nome:'Teclado',preco:28.00},
  {nome:'Mouse',preco:36.00},
  {nome:'Monitor',preco:500.00},
  {nome:'CPU',preco:800.00},
  {nome:'Teclado',preco:28.00},
  {nome:'Monitor',preco:500.00},
];

function somar(arr) {
  let novoLista = [];
  let m = new Map();
  for (let prod of arr) {
    if (m.has(prod.nome)) {
      novoLista[m.get(prod.nome)].preco += prod.preco;
    } else {
      m.set(prod.nome, novoLista.push({
        nome: prod.nome,
        preco: prod.preco
      }) - 1);
    }
  }
  return novoLista;
}

console.log(somar(listaProdutos))
```

Comment: Também coloquei no [benchmark](https://jsbench.me/6xkkroain8/1).

Comment: Obrigado, verificarei todas.

Comment: @LuizFelipe eu peguei o seu código benchmark. Espero que não haja problemas. Quando escrevi esta resposta estava muito cansado. Havia virado a noite brigando com codepoints unicode e foi quando achei uma [resposta aqui no site](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/396555/137387) que municiava para resolver o meu problema.

Answer (score 4):

```js
const listaProdutos = [{
    nome: 'Teclado',
    preco: 28.00
  },
  {
    nome: 'Mouse',
    preco: 36.00
  },
  {
    nome: 'Monitor',
    preco: 500.00
  },
  {
    nome: 'CPU',
    preco: 800.00
  },
  {
    nome: 'Teclado',
    preco: 28.00
  },
  {
    nome: 'Monitor',
    preco: 500.00
  },
];

// Agrupe
const groups = listaProdutos.reduce((acc, current) => {
  if (!acc[current.nome]) {
    acc[current.nome] = { ...current
    }

    return acc
  }

  acc[current.nome].preco = acc[current.nome].preco + current.preco

  return acc
}, {})

// Extraia a lista 
const newList = Object.values(groups)
console.log(newList)
```

Comment: Também coloquei no [benchmark](https://jsbench.me/6xkkroain8/1).

Comment: Pelo que pude ver, essa foi a mais rápida, certo ?

Comment: seria legal adicionar comentários ou na pergunta explicar como fez para agrupar

Comment: Eu vou escolher a resposta amanhã. Cara, o trabalho está me sugando de uma forma absurda. Por um acaso maravilhoso, todas as respostas me serviram. Fico até sem jeito de escolher uma. Se pudesse eu escolheria todas. Muito obrigado mesmo.