# Como pegar valores especificos e conjuntos no JSON

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, match

Tenho o seguinte JSON

```
{
  "navigator.zoom.in": "Zoom +",
  "navigator.zoom.out": "Zoom -",
  "badge_name_BR263": "GAMES 6!",
  "badge_name_BR264": "4Anos",
  "badge_name_X2046": "Cabana Aconchegante",
  "badge_desc_X2046": "Duis interdum viverra ante at hendrerit!",
  "badge_name_HBC049": "Solstício de Natal",
  "badge_desc_HBC049": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellu tincidunt!",
  "badge_name_RHBT102": "Suspendisse nec",
  "badge_desc_RHBT102": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellu",
  "badge_name_RHBT103": "Especial de Natal",
  "badge_desc_RHBT103": "Ho, ho, ho... Feliz Natal! Duis interdum viverra ante at hendrerit. Integer elementum tortor!",
  "badge_name_X2047": "Suspendisse nec",
  "badge_desc_X2047": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit phasellu tincidunt!",
  "navigator.searchcode.title.popular": "Popular",
  "navigator.searchcode.title.chat_chill_discussion": "Conversas",
  "navigator.searchcode.title.games_events": "Jogos"
}
```

primeiramente preciso filtrar somente os `badge_name` e `badge_desc`, consegui filtrar da seguinte maneira

```
const str = JSON.stringify(json);
const match = str.match(/"badge_(name|desc)_(\w+)":"(.*?)"/g).reverse();
```

agora preciso de uma forma de extrair o código depois do `_` e logo depois juntar as badge que tem o código igual, e caso n tenha fica separado, por exemplo

```
//output
Código: X2047
Titulo: Suspendisse nec
Descrição: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit phasellu tincidunt!
...
Código: BR264
Titulo: 4Anos
Descrição: Sem descrição
```

creio que vou ter q passar por um `for of` mas não sei como obter esses dados, fico grato quem conseguir ajudar

Comment: talvez você precise fazer um `map/reduce`  desse objeto pra formar um novo objeto, veja as respostas dessa pergunta que podem te ajudar: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/493586/como-percorrer-um-array-de-objetos-somar-propriedades-espec%c3%adficas-e-unificar-es

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uma possibilidade é iterar o objeto e trabalhar apenas pelas propriedades que começam com `badge_` e em um objeto auxiliar catalogar as informações:

```js
const obj = {
  "navigator.zoom.in": "Zoom +",
  "navigator.zoom.out": "Zoom -",
  "badge_name_BR263": "GAMES 6!",
  "badge_name_BR264": "4Anos",
  "badge_name_X2046": "Cabana Aconchegante",
  "badge_desc_X2046": "Duis interdum viverra ante at hendrerit!",
  "badge_name_HBC049": "Solstício de Natal",
  "badge_desc_HBC049": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellu tincidunt!",
  "badge_name_RHBT102": "Suspendisse nec",
  "badge_desc_RHBT102": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellu",
  "badge_name_RHBT103": "Especial de Natal",
  "badge_desc_RHBT103": "Ho, ho, ho... Feliz Natal! Duis interdum viverra ante at hendrerit. Integer elementum tortor!",
  "badge_name_X2047": "Suspendisse nec",
  "badge_desc_X2047": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit phasellu tincidunt!",
  "navigator.searchcode.title.popular": "Popular",
  "navigator.searchcode.title.chat_chill_discussion": "Conversas",
  "navigator.searchcode.title.games_events": "Jogos"
}

const badges = {}                            //Cria o objeto auxiliar.

/**
 * Indexa uma propriedade e seu valor no objeto auxiliar badges.
 * @function
 * @param {string} p - A propriedade "name"|"desc" que será indexada.
 * @param {string} i - O índice cujo o valor será indexado.
 * @param {string} v - O valor a ser indexado.
 */
function addBadge(p, i, v) {
  //Verifica se i já foi cadastrado...
  if (i in badges) {
    badges[i][p] = v;                       //...se i já foi cadastrado seta a propriedade p com valor v.
  } else {
    badges[i] = {[p]: v};                   //...se p não foi cadastrado cria o índice i setado um novo objeto cujo a propriedade p é setada com o valor v.
  }
}

//Para todos os elementos k:v de obj
for (let [k, v] of Object.entries(obj)) {
  //...se k iniciar com badge_ ...
  if (k.startsWith("badge_")){
    let [_, prop, codigo] = k.split("_");    //...quebra k nos _ separando prop(name/desc) do código numérico.
    addBadge(prop, codigo, v);               //...indexa o valor da propriedade. 
  }
}

//Imprime as propriedades catalogadas.
for (let item in badges) {
  console.log(`Código: ${item}`);
  console.log(`Título: ${badges[item]["name"]}`);
  console.log(`Descrição: ${("desc" in badges[item])?badges[item]["desc"]:"Sem descrição"}`);
  console.log("-------------------------------");
}
```

Referências:

[Object.entries()](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries)
[String.prototype.startsWith()](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startsWith)
[Sintaxe de Espalhamento](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)
[for...of](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of)
[for...in](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in)

Comment: era exatamente o que eu precisava, muito obrigado!