# Passar um parâmetro para um ENUM

Tags: typescript, enums

Eu estou com esse seguinte código aqui:

```
const enum EnumTeste {
    AM = 'após o meio-dia',
    PM= 'depois do meio-dia',
}

let param: string = 'pm'

if(param.toUpperCase() === 'AM') {
    param = EnumTeste.AM
} else if (param.toUpperCase() === 'PM') {
    param = EnumTeste.PM
} else {
    param = 'Não há essa opção'
}

console.log(param) // 'depois do meio-dia'
```

Queria saber se há alguma forma mais fácil/funcional de escrever isso, levando em consideração que o **param** será passado pelo usuário, logo eu não terei controle sobre qual valor será passado ali.

Pergunto isso porque estou levando em consideração, por exemplo, um Enum com estados, ou mesmo países.

Comment: Não tá muito claro para mim o que tu queres... Poderias dar mais detalhes ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode criar um [Proxy](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) sobre um [dicionário](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/27827/137387).

Dicionário é uma estrutura de dados, que associa uma relação de chaves únicas
de pesquisa a respectivos valores. Especificamente no seu caso substitui a enumeração por um objeto de [mapeamento](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html#mapping-modifiers) cujo as propriedades possam ser indexadas por strings:

```
//Declara um dicionário DicTeste cujo as chaves possam indexadas como string.
const DicTeste: {[index: string]: string} = {  
  AM: 'antes o meio-dia',
  PM: 'depois do meio-dia',
}
```

Proxy é um objeto usado para interceptar e redefinir operações fundamentais para outro objeto. Então foi criado um proxy que intercepta a leitura das propriedades do dicionário, convertendo para maiúsculas o nome da propriedade cujo está tentando ser lida e verifica se a propriedade está no dicionário, caso a propriedade esteja no dicionário apenas retorna o seu valor caso contrário retorna uma mensagem informando que não há a opção:

```
//Declara um proxy PDicTeste cujo interceptará a leitura das propriedades de DicTeste.
const PDicTeste = new Proxy(DicTeste,{
  get: function(obj, prop: string) {     //Função de intercepção de leitura das propriedades prop de obj.
    let propU = prop.toUpperCase();      //propU recebe prop em maiúsculas.
    //Caso propU esteja em obj retorne obj[propU] senão retorne uma mensagem personalizada. 
    return propU in obj ? obj[propU] : `Não há essa opção ${prop}`;
  }
});
```

Juntando num exemplo:

```js
const DicTeste: {[index: string]: string} = {  
  AM: 'antes o meio-dia',
  PM: 'depois do meio-dia',
}

const PDicTeste = new Proxy(DicTeste,{
  get: function(obj, prop: string) {
    let propU = prop.toUpperCase();
    return propU in obj ? obj[propU] : `Não há essa opção ${prop}`;
  }
});

let param: string = 'am';
console.log(PDicTeste[param]);

param = 'pM';
console.log(PDicTeste[param]);

param = 'fm';
console.log(PDicTeste[param]);

console.log(PDicTeste.X);
console.log(PDicTeste.AM);
```

Comment: Entendi, eu apenas não queria ficar criando muitos If's. Essa criação de um dicionário ficou bem mais elegante de se apresentar num projeto. Como eu não tenho 'reputação' ainda aqui, eu não vou poder votar para subir. Mas me ajudou muito.