# Inserir dados em um array apenas atualizando os dados que já existirem com a mesma chave/valor

Tags: array, react, typescript

Estou desenvolvendo um front de um webapp para entregas de deliveries e nesta tela coloquei o mapa do google para que o proprietário da empresa possa ver o percurso dos seus motoboys em real-time. Até aqui tudo certo, o map foi simples de implementar, mas o problema em si está na definição dos marcadores do mapa, que são recebidas de um app rodando no celular do motoboy via websocket. De lá é enviado um array de objeto com os dados: latitude, longitude e nome de cada motoboy.

O problema é que cada motoboy envia uma location separadamente e como eu estou armazenando em um state para poder fazer um Array.map e gerar os Markers, ele quebra, pois, a cada novo dado que chega ele sobrescreve o antigo.

Eu tentei realizar alguns metodos com Array.push(), Array.concat() etc... Só que os dados acabam duplicando, como mostra a imagem de exemplo:
[console.log de um teste que fiz](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dUdP8.jpg)

O resultado dessa imagem foi de alguns testes que eu estava fazendo.

Este agora e o código que estou tentando implementar

State que uso para guardar os dados:

```
const [motoboysCoords, setMotoboysCoords] = useState<CoordsProps[]>([]);
```

Trecho que escuto via websocket e recebo os dados dos apps nos celulares dos entregadores

```
useEffect(() => {
        const socket = io(Environment.BASE_URL_SERVER);
        socket.on('receivedPosition', (msg: LocationProps) => {
            setMotoboysCoords([]);
            setMotoboysCoords(oldCoords => oldCoords.concat(msg.localization));
        });
    }, [motoboysCoords]);
```

Neste caso eu queria receber os novos dados, colocar eles no array mantendo os dados antigos caso já haja com o mesmo nome.

Trecho do código dentro do componente GoogleMap onde faço o Array.map():

```
{motoboysCoords.map((item, index) => (
                        <Marker
                            key={index}
                            position={{
                                lat: Number(item.lat),
                                lng: Number(item.long)
                            }}
                        />
                    ))}
```

Comment: Eu não analisei o código pois estou em trânsito. Mas uma sugestão é usar uma tabela de hash cujo a chave seja o date/time de cada coleta de dado

Comment: Bom dia, Augusto. Poderia explicar melhor sobre, nunca ouvi falar de tabela de hash. 
Muito obrigado pela resposta.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/27827/como-funciona-a-implementa%c3%a7%c3%a3o-de-tabelas-hash